# How do you append a list as new rows to a certain column?

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a list and want to append this a Datatframe:

```
List1 = [453, 444]
List2 = ['Mark', 'Owen']
```

My Dataframe:

```
Name      ID     Age:
Sam       123    23
Steve     345    25
```

Intended Output:

```
Name      ID     Age:
Sam       123    23
Steve     345    25
Mark      453    NaN
Owen      444    NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the below:
if "df" is your existing dataframe and List1 = [453, 444]
List2 = ['Mark', 'Owen'] then:

```
df.append({'Name':list2,'AGE':list1}, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

```
import pandas as pd

List1 = [453, 444]
List2 = ['Mark', 'Owen']

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Name = 'Sam Steve'.split(),
    ID = [123, 345],
    Age = [23, 25],
))

df = df.append(
    pd.DataFrame({'Name':List2, 'ID':List1}),
    ignore_index=True,
)
```

[append example in python tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0A%0AList1%20%3D%20%5B453,%20444%5D%0AList2%20%3D%20%5B'Mark',%20'Owen'%5D%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20Name%20%3D%20'Sam%20Steve'.split%28%29,%0A%20%20%20%20ID%20%3D%20%20%20%20%20%5B123,%20345%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20Age%20%3D%20%5B23,%2025%5D,%0A%29%29%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20df.append%28%0A%20%20%20%20pd.DataFrame%28%7B'Name'%3AList2,%20'ID'%3AList1%7D%29,%0A%20%20%20%20ignore_index%3DTrue,%0A%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=7&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Another option is [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat)

```
import pandas as pd

List1 = [453, 444]
List2 = ['Mark', 'Owen']

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Name = 'Sam Steve'.split(),
    ID = [123, 345],
    Age = [23, 25],
))

df = pd.concat([
        df,
        pd.DataFrame({'Name':List2, 'ID':List1})
    ],
    ignore_index=True,
    sort=False,
)
```

[concat example in python tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0A%0AList1%20%3D%20%5B453,%20444%5D%0AList2%20%3D%20%5B'Mark',%20'Owen'%5D%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20Name%20%3D%20'Sam%20Steve'.split%28%29,%0A%20%20%20%20ID%20%3D%20%20%20%20%20%5B123,%20345%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20Age%20%3D%20%5B23,%2025%5D,%0A%29%29%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20pd.concat%28%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20df,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pd.DataFrame%28%7B'Name'%3AList2,%20'ID'%3AList1%7D%29%0A%20%20%20%20%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20ignore_index%3DTrue,%0A%20%20%20%20sort%3DFalse,%0A%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=7&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)